# Localization Select() in ModelForm and Custom RadioSelect() Label

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm searching a way to have localized version of my Select() with Deciaml Values. In Germany we have , as our Separator but Django uses .

Everything with i18n is activated but still I won't get the localized version.
  
  
My Next Question is how could I have a RadioSelect() widget with a custom Label?
The Label Text should come from the model, where the Select gets his input.
Like customer.name, customer.title is this even possible?

Edit i fill the Select() with:

```
    class Article(models.Model):
        cu_inside = models.ForeignKey(CuInside, default='')
        class Meta:
           app_label = 'tasks'
```

and the ForeignKey-Model:

```
class CuInside(models.Model):
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'tasks'
        ordering = ['pk']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.value
```

Now i have a ModelForm:

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'tasks'
        model = Article
        fields = ('cu_inside')
        widgets = {'cu_inside': Select() }
```

so I have nothing special.

The editing / inline of code is really annoying or new for me in stackoverflow..

Comment: How do you fill the `Select` options with data? Please post view and template code.

Comment: Do you have `LOCALE` set to `de-de`? Does your workstation use german locale?

Comment: no i didn't set LOCALE de-de just, LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de-de', and yes my system is german, windows 7 ultimate with german language.

Comment: What about `USE_L10N`? Should be true.

Comment: everything is set, it's just i think that USE_L10N or USE_I18N won't work on ModelForm and Select() Fields.

Comment: Looks like you've hit the feature not yet developed, but already considered in django. Have a look at [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13546). There's also a suggested solution right in the ticket statement. Could you please try that `__init__` trick and let me know if it works?

Comment: that is what i already added and it doesn't work. it still shows me . over , as separator.

Comment: Waaaait a minute :) So, the select is filled with unicode representation of `CuInside` model instance, which is just `u'%s' % self.value`? This has nothing to do with localization, as values are already string by the time they make it to the `Select`. You need to fix the `__unicode__` method. Most likely, it should be as simple as replacing `%s`, `%d` in `__unicode__` method.

Comment: hm how should i change it? with %d it will give me only integers, when i put self.value i wont have localized variables..

Comment: [Read the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) already :) `%n` or `%f`, depending on who are your target audience (scientists and programmers would prefer `%n` or even `%e`, all the rest can't stand those formats, so in love with `%f`)

Comment: at the moment i have return u'{:n}'.format(self.value) but i still get, points and not commas

Comment: Try executing `u'{:n}'.format(3.14)` in interactive python session. Does it output comma or dot as a separator?

Comment: it prints a dot, the problem is with my locale on windows, when i set m locale to 'German' it will be a comma, but thats not a great solution since i will deploy to other operating systems as well, isn't there a better solution for multiple operating systems? in my linux the locale is set already.

Comment: Place [`locale.setlocale`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) in any file that got executed with any request (e.g. settings.py or wsgi.py) and it should be fine. But actually you shouldn't be doing that and just allow django to determine the locale from the client request, like adding `LocaleMiddleware`.

Comment: but, on windows locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '') needs to be 'German', while on Unix its 'de_DE', thats bad also my LocaleMiddleware is loaded, but still my locale is None if i won't set it.